# How to make my slider fully width responsive?

Tags: html, css

I want to make my slider fully responsive, for example, the slider image should span over the whole screen on mobile devices.

You can find my code below. I have tried using a media query but it does not work. I just want the slider to be fully responsive on any kind of device because it works perfectly fine on desktop. I have tested my website with my iPhone 7, but it does not work.

```css
#main-slider {
  position: relative;
}

.no-margin {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#main-slider .carousel .carousel-content {
  margin-top: 150px;
}

#main-slider .carousel .slide-margin {
  margin-top: 140px;
}

#main-slider .carousel h2 {
  color: #fff;
}

#main-slider .carousel .btn-slide {
  padding: 8px 20px;
  background: #534B57;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right
}

#main-slider .carousel .slider-img {
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
}

#main-slider .carousel .item {
  background-position: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  left: 0 !important;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  display: block !important;
  height: 520px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity ease-in-out 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity ease-in-out 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity ease-in-out 500ms;
  transition: opacity ease-in-out 500ms;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#main-slider .carousel .item:first-child {
  top: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<section id="main-slider" class="no-margin">
  <div class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active" style="background-image:url(images/slider/bg7.jpg)">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row slide-margin">
            <div class="col-sm-6 hidden-xs animation animated-item-4">
              <div class="slider-img">
                <img src="images/slider/img1.png" class="img-responsive">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Could you use a [stock image](https://shorturl.at/eotFX) in your code? So that we can see what the actual result is.I guess the bg7.jpg is less important, if not, maybe you upload it here on SO? I don't want to discuss with you why you make your own css slider, but did you consider using one the [many](https://shorturl.at/xCER0) working [sliders](https://shorturl.at/ltvw7)? I ended up using [Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/) because it was the only one adapting easily a changing amount of pictures. Because transitions in CSS although performant, are hard to debug, generate, sync with html etc

Answer (score 0):

To suggest a solution, instead of making the margin to be 0, on the **no-margin class**... Make it in this format to widen compactability

`.no-margin{ margin:auto; padding:0px; }`

If that doesn't help add a max-width and give something like 70px or more to the **no-margine class**
`max-width:70px;`

Comment: Alright, I'll make more research.. Thanks @AhmedKhorshed